# How could integrate NextJS app in another website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, next.js

I've been looking for a way to integrate a React/NextJS application into another application.

The only way I have come up with is through an iframe, and putting in the src of it, the execution of the React/Nextjs application.

Is there any other way to make this use case? I have been investigating and I have not found anything that was not using an iframe.

Thank you very much,
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Reach this question because I had the same question, not for a specific need but conceptually. At this point I'd say that there is no other way.

Next JS runs in both browser and server runtime environments (React and Node) and it handles the GET requests of a user navigation through the browser as entry point to handle anything needed before that.

When using an E2E framework like that, the usual pattern is to integrate other apps that can be raised stand-alone (such React only, angular... App) inside the one that can handle everything (Next JS).

Take a look at [multi-zones](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones) feature.